# Getting Milliseconds from Calendar for a Month

Tags: android

How can I get Time in Millisecond from Calendar Object in order to set an interval in Alarm Manager I am using the following code:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, sender);
```

and my calculation for `interval` for getting One month of MilliSeconds is as follows:

```
Calendar monthCal = Calendar.getInstance();
monthCal.clear();
monthCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
monthCal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

interval =  monthCal.getTimeInMillis();
```

but I am not getting any repeating Alarms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year,month,1); // Set the year and month you want milliseconds for
long daysInMonth = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE); //Get how many days this month have
long millisInMonth = daysInMonth*dayMillis; //Multiply the amount of days with how many milliseconds a day consists of (86400000L)
```